# How to organize queues for each request-handling in new thread?

Tags: c, multithreading, http, sockets

I need help with organizing each request-handling for incoming connection in new thread (code is at the bottom of this topic).

I don't know at all how to organize manually ( without using boost/threadpool ) queue with handling each request? How should I solve such problem with non-using boost etc?

Cause, I want do it manually, and I don't understand how do the next:

- Listening for each new connection
- If I've got new connection, then send in new thread the handling
- When thread ends handling process, close this thread

I have tried to do such stuff with *while(true);* but don't know how to organize well the request-queue to handle each HTTP-request.

My code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

typedef struct Header
{
friend struct Net;

private:
    WORD wsa_version;
    WSAData wsa_data;

    SOCKET sock;
    SOCKADDR_IN service;

    char *ip;
    unsigned short port;

public:
    Header(void)
    {
        wsa_version = 0x202;

        ip = "0x7f.0.0.1";
        port = 0x51;

        service.sin_family = AF_INET;
        service.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip);
        service.sin_port = htons(port);
    }

} Header;

typedef struct Net
{
private:
    int result;

    HANDLE thrd;
    DWORD exit_code;

    void WSAInit(WSAData *data, WORD *wsa_version)
    {
        result = WSAStartup(*wsa_version, &(*data));

        if(result != NO_ERROR)
        {
            std::cout << "WSAStartup() failed with the error: " << result << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << (*data).szDescription << " " << (*data).szSystemStatus << std::endl;
        }
    }

    void SocketInit(SOCKET *my_socket)
    {
        (*my_socket) = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

        if((*my_socket) == INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            std::cout << "Socket initialization failed with the error: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
            WSACleanup();
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Socket initialization successful!" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    void SocketBind(SOCKET *my_socket, SOCKADDR_IN *service)
    {
        result = bind((*my_socket), (SOCKADDR*)&(*service), sizeof(*service));

        if(result == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            std::cout << "Socket binding failed with the error: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
            closesocket((*my_socket));
            WSACleanup();
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Socket binding successful!" << std::endl;
        }

        result = listen(*my_socket, SOMAXCONN);

        if(result == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            std::cout << "Socket listening failed with the error: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Listening to the socket..." << std::endl;
        }
    }

    void SocketAccept(SOCKET *my_socket)
    {
        SOCKET sock_accept = accept((*my_socket), 0, 0);

        if(sock_accept == INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            std::cout << "Accept failed with the error: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
            closesocket(*my_socket);
            WSACleanup();
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Client socket connected!" << std::endl;

            thrd = CreateThread(NULL, 0, &Net::Threading, &sock_accept, 0, NULL);
        }
    }

    static void HandleRequest(char response[], int length)
    {
        std::cout << std::endl;

        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            std::cout << response[i];
        }

        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    static DWORD WINAPI Threading(LPVOID lpParam)
    {
        SOCKET *my_socket = (SOCKET*)lpParam;

        char data[0x400];
        int result = recv((*my_socket), data, sizeof(data), 0);
        HandleRequest(data, result);
        char *response = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nServer: Amegas.sys-IS/1.0\r\nContent-type: text/html\r\nSet-Cookie: ASD643DUQE7423HFDG; path=/\r\nCache-control: private\r\n\r\n<h1>Hello World!</h1>\r\n\r\n";
        result = send((*my_socket), response, (int)strlen(response), 0);

        if(result == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            std::cout << "Sending data via socket failed with the error: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
            closesocket((*my_socket));
            WSACleanup();
        }
        else
        {
            result = shutdown((*my_socket), 2);
        }

        return 0;
    }

public:
    Net(void)
    {
        Header *obj_h = new Header();

        WSAInit(&obj_h->wsa_data, &obj_h->wsa_version);

        SocketInit(&obj_h->sock);
        SocketBind(&obj_h->sock, &obj_h->service);

        SocketAccept(&obj_h->sock);

        delete obj_h;
    }
} Net;

int main(void)
{
    Net *obj_net = new Net();

    delete obj_net;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your OS will handle the accept() queueing - don't worry too much about it.  Simple synchronous servers tend to run like this:

```
socket listeningSocket:=socket.create;
listeningSocket.bind('0.0.0.0',80);  // address/port
listeningSocket.listen;

while(true){
  socket serverClientSocket=accept(listeningSocket);
  createThread(&serverClientThread,serverClientSocket);
}

void serverClientThread(void *param)
{
  inBuffer char[256];
  socket myServerClientSocket=(socket)param;
  while(true){
     int bytesRx=recv(myServerClientSocket,&inBuffer,size(inBuffer));
     if (bytesRx>0){
        if doSomethingWith(&inBuffer,bytesRx) // not necessarily size(inBuffer) bytes!!
        {
           send(myServerClientSocket,"Reply from server\r\n");
        }

     }
     else
       return; // on error or connection closed
  }
}
```

The one listening thread, (can be main thread in console apps), runs the accept() loop foerver.  The separate serverClientThread instances run until their client disconects or some other error occurs.

Comment: Does someone think that this is factually inaccurate or misleading?

Comment: +1 Boy that's tough Martin.  Can you get a moderator involved?  Maybe post on meta?